# Gatling request is not getting executed

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

```
    val makeReport =
      feed(randomNumberFeeder)
        .exec( session => {
          http("post_report")
            .post("/api/path/reports")
            .body(StringBody(JsonFactory.report(id = 1, number= session("number").asOption[String].get))).asJson
            .check(jsonPath("$.reportId").saveAs("reportId"))
          session
        })

val scn = scenario("ReportCreation").exec(makeReport)
```

But When I run the Gatling tests the request is not being sent, and the whole HTTP block is ignored. Where am I going wrong?

So I am end up with the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
    at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:50)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:65)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:40)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

Comment: Read the warning in the documentation. https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/

Comment: I read it, But I could not figure out how to use doIf for this purpose. I could not find a proper example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

```
      val makeReport =
      feed(randomNumberFeeder)
        .exec(http("post_report")
            .post("/api/path/reports")
            .body(StringBody( session => JsonFactory.report(id = 1, number= session("number").as[String]))).asJson
            .check(jsonPath("$.reportId").saveAs("reportId"))

        })
```